# datatables.net: how to use responsive plus checkbox in datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

i am using Datatable.net framework for tables.

my problem is this i want 2 thing in same datatable one is responsive and 2nd is Checkbox.

**this is script i am using for this**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'tr'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

**this is HTML i am using.**

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you add responsive library which comes from with datatables plugin in your page

Comment: yes i added and its worked ... if i using checkbox then it is not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something, if you want use Datatables's extensions then you should add extensions library, otherwise it won't work,

So you can see working code in this link  [jsfiddle.net/1eLg1Lgy/](https://jsfiddle.net/1eLg1Lgy/)

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'tr'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>$320,800</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and extension link is here [cdn.datatables.net/#Extensions](https://cdn.datatables.net/#Extensions)

Comment: thank for reply ... @ferhat your code is working . i want multiple checkbox selection.

Comment: in the mobile there is no 'ctrl' button. what we do there?

Comment: Why do you need the 'ctrl' button, if you explain that what do you want to do then we can find solution.